# How do you debug pydoit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, doit

I have a python doit script that is getting stuck on one step but doesn't throw an error.  It would sit all day if I let it.  I've checked all the inputs and they look exactly the same as the last time I ran it.  How do I debug?  I tried using pdb but maybe I don't know how to use it and I googled and couldn't find example code.  I can't post my code since its confidential.  Just a general how to debug in doit would help me greatly.  I use Python 2.7 and yes eventually I'll have to update to 3 but for now I'm using 2.7. (Sorry I have had quite a few ask why I continue with 2.7--- no time right now to update all my scripts, there are over 200)

Comment: Why not just learn how to use PDB? Actually, I'd search for videos in this particular case, because it's a "visual" thing, but that's just my preference. Why can't you extract a [mcve] from your script and post that here? That would also make it easier for you to learn debugging it, due to its decreased scope. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

https://pydoit.org/tools.html#set-trace

`doit` provides a `set_trace()` function that will call PDB `set_trace` and make sure stdout output is printed on terminal.

Not your case, but `doit` also provides a command line option `--pdb` that automatically drops in PDB when an unhandled exception occurs.